# Apache logs out unknown IP address

Tags: wordpress, apache, logging

I frequently (10 per sec) receive requests to my wordpress website.

See my apache access log:

```
www.mydomain.de:80 dedicated.server - - [16/Oct/2016:21:56:26 +0200] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 403 477 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
```

How do I figure out which ip is trying to access my apache webserver?

And how do I block it?

Normally I see an IP address but this log only shows "**dedicated.server**".

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [`mod-log` docs](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_log_config), for `%h` format string:

1. You might have the [`HostnameLookups` directive](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/core#hostnamelookups) set to *On*.
2. You might be defining them by name somewhere else.

I'd recommend using `%a` format string to log the client IP address.